# Use aggregation only on rows where count(ID) is greater than one

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have the following table

**Cash_table**

```
ID          Cash   Rates
1           50   3
2           100  4
3           70   10
3           60   10
4           13   7
5           20   8
5           10   10
6           10   5
```

What I want as a result is to cumulate all the entries that have a **Count(id)>1** like this:

```
ID          New_Cash            New_Rates
1           50                  3
2           100                 4
3           (70+60)/(10+10)     10+10
4           13                  7
5           (20+10)/(8+10)      8+10
6           10                  5
```

So I only want to change the rows where Count(id)>1 and leave the rest like it was.

For the rows with count(id)>1 I want to sum up the rates and take the sum of the cash and divide it by the sum of the rates. The Rates alone aren't a problem since I can sum them up and group by id and get the desired result.

The problem is with the cash column:

I am trying to do it with a case statement but it isn't working:

```
   select id, sum(rates) as new_rates, case 
   when count(id)>1 then sum(cash)/nullif(sum(rates),0))
   else cash
   end as new_cash
   from Cash_table
   group by id
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need `group by id` and aggregate:

```
 select 
   id,
   sum(cash) / (case count(*) when 1 then 1 else sum(rates) end) as new_cash, 
   sum(rates) as new_rates
 from Cash_table
 group by id
 order by id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dddb3ba6bb9979811824d442bfe4d331).

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate `rate` and `cash` columns by `sum()` function with grouping by id

```
select 
       id,             
       sum(cash)/decode( sum( nvl(rates,0) ), 0 ,1, sum( nvl(rates,0) )) as new_cash,
       sum(rates) as new_rates 
  from cash_table
 group by id
```

- there's no `nullif()` function in Oracle, use `nvl()` instead
- switch case part ( where `decode()` function is used ) against the
  possibility of division by zero